# MS SQL Stored procedure for selecting random items where sum of selected cols will be greater than input value

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I'm newbie in SQL so I need help. I've got two tables.

### First: CategoriesToQuestions

```
+----+------------+------------+
| Id | CategoryId | QuestionId |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 |          1 |          1 |
|  2 |          2 |          2 |
|  3 |          1 |          3 |
|  4 |          3 |          4 |
+----+------------+------------+
```

### Second: Questions

```
+-----+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------------+-----------+-------+
| Id  |  Question  | Answer1 | Answer2 | Answer3 | Answer4 | ContextType |   ContextUrl    | IsFirstCorrect | IsSecondCorrect | IsThirdCorrect | IsFourthCorrect | IsFreeVersion | IsExtendedQuestion | SectionId | Score |
+-----+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------------+-----------+-------+
|   1 | Question 1 | A       | B       | C       | D       |           0 | http://null.com | False          | False           | False          | True            | True          | False              |         1 |     2 |
|   2 | Question 2 | A       | B       | C       | D       |           0 | http://null.com | False          | True            | False          | False           | True          | False              |         5 |     4 |
|   3 | Question 3 | A       | B       | C       | D       |           0 | http://null.com | False          | False           | True           | True            | False         | False              |         3 |     5 |
|   4 | Question 4 | A       | B       | C       | D       |           0 | http://null.com | True           | False           | False          | True            | True          | False              |         6 |     1 |
+-----+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------------+-----------+-------+
```

In CategoriesToQuestions table I've got relations for Category and Questions (one Category can have many Questions and Questions can have many Categories).

I must write stored procedure for getting X random rows from Questions table for one Category, where sum of all cols named Score equals or is greater than input value and IsExtendedQuestion is only true or false.

I've got something like this, but it doesn't work properly:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetQuestionsForExam
    @categoryId int, 
    @extendedQuestions bit, 
    @questionsCount int, 
    @scoreValue int
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP (@questionsCount) * FROM Questions WHERE Id 
    IN (SELECT questionId FROM CategoriesToQuestions WHERE categoryId = @categoryId)
    AND IsExtendedQuestion = @extendedQuestions
    HAVING SUM(Score) >= @scoreValue
    ORDER BY NEWID()
END
```

Comment: Please post your data as text. Images are impossible to work with unfortunately. Here's a good formatter. https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: @scsimon You're welcome :)

Comment: starting from SQL-2012 you can use running total, example is here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3301a/7, am to lazy to use all your conditions in example

Comment: Given the sample data, can you provide an example procedure call with parameters populated and the expected output of it?

Comment: @tarheel It's more complicated problem than I excepted called knapsack problem. I'm trying to solve that problem with my friend. Given response in comments don't solve that. When I will finish I will give you response with example procedure :)